# jquery turning "on" and "off" event handlers

Tags: jquery, events

How would I apply the "off" directive to a named handler?

ex

```
var $btn = $("#theBtn");
var namedHandler = $btn.on("click", function() {
//do something
//then turn off
})
```

would I turn it off like this

```
$btn.off("click");
```

or could I do something else now it is stored in a variable?

```
namedHandler.off("click");
```

or

```
namedHandler.off();
```

etc.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same reference to the jQuery object will be in `$btn` *and* `namedHandler`. Both return a reference to the same thing so the assignment is assigning the same thing.

You could turn it `off()` with either method.

What may be more suited to your example is [*namespacing* your event](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events), so `off('click', ...)` won't unbind *all* `click` events.

Comment: That's pretty much what I wanted to know. the named handler is just storing a jquery object and not some event handling logic. great

Answer (score 13):

You can also do this

```
function handleClick(event) 
{
    // code
}

$('#btn').on('click', handleClick);

$('#btn').off('click', handleClick);
```

Some usefull examples only about on/off [here](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/).

Answer (score 8):

*In addition to what @alex & @WereWolf said, I often find this useful :*

For a single use event handler, you can use `.one()` instead of `.on()` followed by `.off()`

```
$( "#foo" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This is rather a comment, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a function for your handler and pass it to `.off()` to disable that handler and `.on()` to reenable it.

The documentation provides examples to achieve this

http://api.jquery.com/off/

```
function aClick() {
  $("div").show().fadeOut("slow");
}
$("#bind").click(function () {
  $("body").on("click", "#theone", aClick)
    .find("#theone").text("Can Click!");
});
$("#unbind").click(function () {
  $("body").off("click", "#theone", aClick)
    .find("#theone").text("Does nothing...");
});
```